# Free alternative to standard C# DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

The standard DataGrid is quite unresponsive when it comes to displaying large amounts of information. I tried SourceGrid and can live with the results, but see room for improvement. Can anyone think of any other free alternatives to the standard DataGrid that can handle large amounts of data? I am open to creative ideas.

Comment: Which DataGrid are you talking about ? WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, Silverlight ?

Comment: I am always surprised by the frequency of UI-related questions that don't specify the platform. I wonder if tags like datagrid should be broken up into wpf-datagrid, winforms-datagrid, etc.

Comment: I am referring to the standard DataGrid for WinForms found in Visual Studio.

Comment: I added the winforms tag for you.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I also feel that I should emphasize that I am trying to display a _large_ amount of data (tens of thousands of rows) to the user.

Comment: WinForms has a DataGridView. Are you using an older version, ie .NET 2?

Comment: Hard to see why perf would matter, the user will need a long time to find the record back.  Give her a way to filter the result set, you'll automatically get a faster grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking into XPTable and trying out ObjectListView, I've decided that SourceGrid is superior (speed wise) to both for large quantities of data, scrolling feels much smoother.

Answer (score 4):

How about [XPTable](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/XPTableListViewUpdate.aspx) on CodeProject? Ok, it is a modified form of ListView but that might suffice and lighter. The source code is on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xptable/) as it is more up-to-date then on CodeProject. A newer clone is available on [github](https://github.com/schoetbi/XPTable).

There is also a custom DataGrid here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/csharpgridcontrol.aspx) called SourceGrid, the source repository resides on github [here](https://github.com/siemens/SourceGrid).

Answer (score 3):

I've heard good things about [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) but I haven't used it. It seems to have a very rich feature set. In the past when I used Windows Forms I would have killed for some of the issues it solves as compared to ListView. Note that it's not a DataGrid however.

Not to sound like a shill but although you said free alternative, I still should mention the best Windows Forms datagrid I've ever used was Developer Express's XtraGrid. I've yet to see any grid in any UI technology come close to it in terms of usability and features.

Comment: Josh, ObjectListView looks promising, I haven't given much thought to using list view objects in the past, but now I think I should reconsider. Since I need to display huge amounts of data to the user (tens of thousands of rows), I am looking for a fast and light implementation. The XtraGrid you mentioned looks very feature rich, but I am just a student and cannot afford commercial options.

Comment: ObjectListView includes a DataListView which is designed for data binding scenarios and I'm sure it supports virtualization. That's the key - with a huge number of objects you need a control that supports "virtual mode" which just means the control only creates row objects for the currently visible items.

Answer (score 2):

[Component Factory's Krypton toolkit](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton/) has a nice looking one.  It is free, however, I've never used it so I can't speak for or against it.